# Listing/grouping variables in PowerPivot table field list

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table, powerpivot

I have data with 60+ variables and I would like to group the variables into different collapsible fields in a pivot table, similar to having different tables in the pivot field list - ie, instead of having all 60 variables in the same long list. A bit like creating sets, but allowing the set members to still be chosen individually.

I have tried splitting the variables into different pivot tables, but it's a tedious process to do manually and hard if not impossible to do automatically using PowerPivot. I have also tried to split them with perspectives, but that is a bit difficult to maintain, because the variables change over time and I would like to make it as easy to use as possible (the end user wouldn't have to touch anything but the charts or maybe some macro button). Is there a simpler way of doing this?

I'm happy with either PowerPivot or a normal pivot table based solution. Using VBA isn't a problem either.

Edit: Here is a picture that hopefully demonstrates what I am trying to achieve, grouping without splitting data into multiple tables:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Pivot tables have grouping/collapsing functionality. Can you give an example?

Comment: I have one pivot table with all the variables and I would like to group the variables into subfolders, so they're easier to find, without creating another table. For example I have table with few different throughput measurements and error rates. I would like to group the throughput measurements into their own "sub folder" and error rates into their own "folder", in a way that they're still individually selectable.

Comment: I edited a picture link to my original post, which will hopefully clarify what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way you can do this. For each "folder" you'll need to create a dummy PowerPivot table to hold the calculated measures.

The simplest way to do this is to create some linked tables. For example, let's say you want "folders" to hold your **Errors** and **Goals** measures. Create these tables on your worksheet and for each click the `Create Linked Table` button on the ribbon.

[image]

In the PowerPivot window make sure these new tables are named as you desire - these will be your "folder" names: I've used **VarErrors** and **VarGoals**. Don't try and link them to any other table - allow them to be independent.

[image]

Now you can start allocating measures to folders. For each existing measure, edit it (go into `Measure Settings` and set the `Table name` to be the variable "folder" that you want.

[image]

That's it!

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! My work contract ended, so I won't be able to test your solution. I will mark your post as the answer anyway, as it seems to be doing what i wanted =)

Comment: Shame I only saw your question recently... still, at least you know for next time :)

Comment: Actually I've found myself using this technique in my own PowerPivots lately... Thanks for asking the question!